# X-cart run Google Shipping Export from cron (login from extrnal script)

Tags: php, x-cart

I am trying to set up the Google Shipping export to run as a cron job, instead of interactively from Admin.

We are using X-Cart 4.7.7.  I am new to X-Cart, and can't find documentation.  Basically I know that my PHP script will have to log in to X-Cart before it can invoke the existing scripts.  I would appreciate any help in how I set this up.

Answer (score 0):

The possible way to go is

1)Modify the file 
modules/Froogle/config.php
and add a new  cron task

```
$cron_tasks[] = array(
    'function' => 'func_froogle_cron_update',
    'include'  => $xcart_dir . '/modules/Froogle/func.php',
);
```

2)Add the function func_froogle_cron_update

The function should include the file 
modules/Froogle/froogle.php and emulate a regular POST request to create a new feed file.

3) Setup a new cron job according to 
https://help.x-cart.com/index.php?title=X-Cart:Cron.php_-_Script_for_Periodic_Tasks

Meanwhile, the feature is added in X-Cart 4.7.10

A patch for X-Cart 4.7.9 is here 
https://bt.x-cart.com/view.php?id=49137#attachments

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)